# Can I run a stakepool on a home router without a fixed IP address?

Tags: node

My ISP assigns an IP address to my internet modem -- it's not a permanently assigned static IP address but stays the same for months or years. Can I use the NAT service on my router to channel the ports to an internal node running on my home network?

Answer (score 4):

You could but it is not recommended. You could use DynDNS service, associate the address with an actual DNS entry from your domain. But, from years of experience managing infrastructures, you will run into problems.